# Jfrog Upgrade from 6.17 to 7.x

Tags: upgrade, jfrog-container-registry

I am working on upgrading **Jfrog 6.17 Pro** to the closest **Jfrog 7.X** version. Any idea if I can directly upgrade to latest version 7.6 available.

My current installation is done using **.zip file** on Linux OS. For the latest release I don't see a .zip package download option for Linux, can I use **.tar file** instead?.

Also the directory layout has been changed in 7.x version.

I have looked at the documentation provided by Jfrog and its not very clear how I can upgrade. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

@syed You can upgrade from 6.17 to latest. But you need to manually copy some folders into the new structure as mentioned in the  upgrade documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-LinuxArchiveUpgrade)

If you felt documentation steps are unclear please raise them here, and we can help.

Make sure these three are set correctly while running those copy commands:

```
    export ARTIFACTORY_HOME=<Path to your current Artifactory installation>
    export JFROG_HOME=<Full path to jfrog directory of new version, for example: /opt/jfrog>
    export JF_PRODUCT_HOME=$JFROG_HOME/artifactory
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. JFrog documentation does not mention why .Zip file format has been removed for linux. Also it must have been mentioned for the old users who are using .zip file installation and steps to migrate to the .tar format.

A latest version 7.7.3 of Jfrog available today. There are no release notes for the latest releases for 7.7.X versions. I only see release notes for 7.6.X versions. Does that mean the latest 7.7.x version are less stable when compared to 7.6.x. Please clarify.

Is it safe to upgrade to 7.7.x version?

Comment: Release notes for artifactory is here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.7.  Also, if you had zip install, there is no change to upgrade using the tar - the documented steps should work. Let me know if this is not the case.